# Show that if you paint 6 dots on the unit square, then there is always a couple of 2 points with distance <=2/3

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

This question is difficult for me. Anyone knows how to divide the unit square by using pigeonhole principle?

Comment: Duplicate of [Prove that having 6 points in the interior of a square](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1403013) where the answer is posted within the question.